# IoT Hub - Per Device Throttling

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

After reading through the docs around IoT Hub quotas and throttling (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling), the throttling appears to be per the hub and not per the device, is that a correct assumption?

If that is the case is there an elegant way to set quotas per device so that particularly chatty devices can be throttled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct, Quotas and throttle limits are per hub or per unit of IoT hub. You would have to throttle it on the device IoT clients yourself. I dont think there is anyway to prevent IoT Hub from receiving a message from a registered and enabled device.

There is a provision to [disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#disable-devices) the device on IoT hub. You can explore if there is an API to do this programmatically and disable a device. And then you could enable it again after sometime. But this could be very problematic if not managed well. So think through your use-cases very carefully before you think of this option. IMO it is best to throttle from device itself.